# repeat rotation without animation C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, rotation

I have this function that rotates the model 15degrees every time I double click with the mouse on the model. It rotates on the Y axis and every time it rotates the camera moves up so the model will stay in the scene and will not disappear after 3 double-clicks.

It needs 24 double-clicks for the model to rotate and come back to it's initial position, So what I want to do is to double-click only once and the model will do the 360 degrees automatically, but I want to do that without using animation. I tried to to that with a for loop in "SpatialMouse-Doubleclick" function but didn't work.
For example if I at a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

the model will be displayed at it's final position only.

Is there anyway I can view the steps of the for loop like animation instead of the last step only?
Or is there any other way I can do the rotation using my code and with no animation?

```
private void SetViewPosition()
{
    Vector3D vAxis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
    //R= AxisAngleRotation3D
    AxisAngleRotation3D myRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vAxis, -45);
    RotateTransform3D myRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(myRotation);
    gCamWC = myRotationTransform.Value;
    gCamWC.M14 = -13;
    gCamWC.M24 = 0;
    gCamWC.M34 = 13;

    Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14,gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
    Vector3D startLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);
    Vector3D startLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);

    DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(camPosition, startLookAt, startLookUp, 0);

}

private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Vector3D vAxis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);

    AxisAngleRotation3D myRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vAxis, -15);
    RotateTransform3D myRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(myRotation);
    Matrix3D doTranslation = new Matrix3D();
    doTranslation.M34 = 4;
    gCamWC.Append(myRotationTransform.Value);
    gCamWC.Append(doTranslation);

    Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14, gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
    Vector3D camLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);
    Vector3D camLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);

    DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(camPosition, camLookAt, camLookUp,0);
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I renamed the function **SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick** to **RotatingModel**
and changed the "MouseButtonEventArgs" to "EventArgs".

Then I added the following code to the Function where I want **RotatingModel()** to be called.

```
//Add Dispatcer Time so the Rotation will be repeated
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += RotatingModel;
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);//(h,m,s)
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Now when I Debug my project the model rotates 15degrees every 1 second automatically.

Comment: If you do something lke this in a loop, you must call something in the loop that forces your drawing surface to invalidate its client area and redraw at the end of each loop iteration. Lookup Control.Refresh(). If you don't, you'll get exactly what you described, you only see the final position.

Comment: Depending on how fast the calculation and render run, you may need to add a pause in the loop as well. Something like Thread.Sleep

Comment: @Kevin Control.Refresh is WinForms, not WPF. Thread.Sleep will block the UI thread. Both are bad advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the lack of a delay causes the for loop to complete too quickly, one possible solution may be to use a Timer object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

The Timer has an Interval that you can set to any number of milliseconds, and it has an Elapsed event. You can experiment with the Interval until the rotation speed seems right.

Note:
"If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or BeginInvoke. Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the DispatcherTimer."
(Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Better use DispatcherTimer, because it already runs in the UI thread.

Comment: Dispathcer works perfectly. Thank you @Clemens and Ken M :)
I will add my Solution in My Question